# Rails Migration内でのexecute >> SQLでUnicodeキャラクターが常にnullを返します

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, unicode

現在以下のことをしようとしています。

1. ユーザーの名前(Name)をsplitted_nameという変数に代入。
2. splitted_name[0]をfirst_nameに保存(first_name = splitted_name[0])
3. splitted_name[0]とsplitted_name[-1]が別の値であればlast_nameにsplitted_name[-1]を保存

以下がコードです。

```
class ConvertNameIntoFirstAndLastName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      DO
      $do$
      DECLARE
        u record;
      BEGIN
      FOR u IN SELECT * FROM users LOOP
        DECLARE
          splitted_name text[];
        BEGIN
          splitted_name := CASE WHEN u.name IS NULL THEN '{''}'
                                ELSE regexp_split_to_array(u.name, E'\\s+')
                           END;
          UPDATE users
            SET 
              first_name = splitted_name[0],
              last_name = CASE WHEN splitted_name[0] = splitted_name[-1] THEN ''
                               ELSE splitted_name[-1]
                          END,
              name = splitted_name[0] || ' ' || (CASE WHEN splitted_name[0] = splitted_name[-1] THEN '{''}'
                                                      ELSE splitted_name[-1]
                                                END)
          WHERE id = u.id;
        END;
      END LOOP;
      END;
      $do$;
    SQL
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

しかし、漢字でnameが保存されている場合にこのSQL文のu.nameが常にnullを返します。(DBのエンコーディングはUnicodeに設定されています。)

下記がエラー内容です。

PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
=> 実際にはnameはnullではなく漢字のstringが入っています。

どなたか同様の問題を解決された方はいるでしょうか？原因と解決法がわかると助かります。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

すみません。勉強不足でPostgresqlでArrayの最初の値がArray[0]Array[1]でないと取得出来ないことや、Array[-1]が無いことを知りませんでした。

以下のコードで動きました。

```
class ConvertNameIntoFirstAndLastName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      DO
      $do$
      DECLARE
        u record;
      BEGIN
      FOR u IN SELECT * FROM users LOOP
        DECLARE
          splitted_name text[];
        BEGIN
          splitted_name := regexp_split_to_array(regexp_replace(u.name, '　', ' '), ' ');
          UPDATE users
            SET 
              first_name = splitted_name[1],
              last_name = CASE WHEN splitted_name[1] = splitted_name[array_upper(splitted_name, 1)] THEN ''
                               ELSE splitted_name[array_upper(splitted_name, 1)]
                          END,
              name = splitted_name[1] || ' ' || (CASE WHEN splitted_name[1] = splitted_name[array_upper(splitted_name, 1)] THEN ''
                                                      ELSE splitted_name[array_upper(splitted_name, 1)]
                                                END)
          WHERE id = u.id;
        END;
      END LOOP;
      END;
      $do$;
    SQL
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

「そもそも論」ですが、Railsのマイグレーションはスキーマの変更（テーブルやカラムの追加、インデックスの変更、etc）を目的としているので、既存データの変更に使うのは本来の用途から少し外れている気がします。（db:rollback でデータを元に戻すのもほとんど無理でしょうし）

参考： [Active Record マイグレーション | Rails ガイド](http://railsguides.jp/active_record_migrations.html)

あと、コードを見たところどうしてもDB上でやらなければいけない処理のようにも見えなかったので、Rails側で処理した方が簡単に書ける気がしました。

たとえば以下のような変換用のメソッドを用意して、それをサーバー上のrails consoleで実行する、というのも一つの方法です。

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.convert_name_into_first_and_last_name
    self.transaction do
      self.all.each do |user|
        splitted_name = user.name.split(/[ 　]+/)
        user.first_name = splitted_name.first
        # splitted_nameが3つ以上に分割されている場合は別途考慮が必要
        user.last_name = splitted_name.size == 2 ? splitted_name.last : ''
        user.name = splitted_name.join(' ')
        user.save!
      end
    end
  end
end

# rails console
User.convert_name_into_first_and_last_name
```

こうしておくと、変更処理のテストコードも書きやすくなります。

よかったらこういう方法も検討してみてください。